# MongoDB top 3 entries

Tags: mongodb

I would like to get the most 3 accessed (popular) entries from my Location table and return their ID's. How can I do that?
My Location table contains name,logitude,latitude and city[].

Comment: Do I need to keep a variable and increse it everytime the Location is used? Or it's something simpler with MongoDB functions? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to track the number of times the document has been fetched.  You can do this with:

```js
doc = db.foo.findOneAndUpdate({name:'X'},{$inc: {count:1}}, {returnDocument: 'after'});
```

Each time you call `findOneAndUpdate`, the field `count` will be incremented and the whole doc returned.

To find the top 3 most popular Locations, simply use `sort` and `limit`:

```js
db.foo.find().sort({count:-1}).limit(3);
```